# Send the row values of a Jquery Datatable to a new form

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a working script that retreives data into a table.
I want to add an edit link, so that when I click on Edit, 
it gets to a page where I can modify data to update the DB.

The working script is the following:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#tabla').DataTable({
        scrollY:        '40vh',
        scrollCollapse: true,
        paging:         true,
    ajax:{
    method: "POST",
    url: "/ServletList",
    dataSrc: "datos"
    },
    "serverSide": true,
    "processing": true,
    "columns": [
        {"data": "id","searchable":false},
        {"data": "name","searchable":true},
        {"data": "city","searchable":true},
        {"data": "country","searchable":true},
    ]   
    });
    });
</script>
```

And I have added the following lines to the columns section:

```
{"mRender": function ( data, type, row ) {
    return '<a href=edit.jsp?id='+row.id+'>Edit</a>';}
}
```

edit.jsp is a form that will update a value of the DB once it is filled.

My question is how do I pass to the edit.jsp the values that I have selected in the row:
id, name, city, country

Comment: You are already 90% of the way to a solution. Just continue - for example: `return '<a href=edit.jsp?id=' + row.id + '&name=' + row.name + '&city=' + row.city + '&country=' + row.country + '>Edit</a>';`. This will create a link with all the row data included as query parameters: `edit.jsp?id=123&name=foo&city=bar&country=baz` Your JSP form will receive the GET and it can extract the parameters in the usual way. No need for extra onclick events or DOM access. The data is all there in the `row` variable provided by DataTables.

Comment: Hi Andrew ! It works perfect so far. I am reading the value with a function getParameterByName(name, url). I am only having one problem now ... For instance the country field can include spaces: let's say "NEW ZEALAND", and in the URL that I read, I only get up to "NEW" ... I am looking for a solution ... Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do this several ways, but the one came to my mind is this:

- The edit link will trigger on click a function
- This function will fetch all row fields (related to clicked link row)
- Get the values of those fields and shape them like url string
- Redirect to edit.jsp page and read the URL which contains values

Code to do so:

```
{"mRender": function ( data, type, row ) {
    return '<a href="javascript:;" data-url="edit.jsp?id='+row.id+'" onclick="EditRowData(this);">Edit</a>';}
}
```

and the **EditRowData** function code is:

```
<script>
    function EditRowData(element) {
        urlToEditPage = $(element).attr('data-url');
        firstValue = $(element).parents('tr').find('.firstInput').val();
        secondValue = $(element).parents('tr').find('.secondInput').val();
        //... add values as you want
        window.location.href = urlToEditPage + '&firstValue=' + firstValue + '&secondValue=' + secondValue
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your proposal !! I am testing right now the other solution: return '<a href=edit.jsp?id=' + row.id + '&name=' + row.name + '&city=' + row.city + '&country=' + row.country + '>Edit</a>'; It is partially working for me except that I need to include spaces. Thank you so much.

Comment: Hi, Great to know that, in my code sample you can see, it considers inputs for each cell in the row as I thought this is what you are using.

However, to be honest with you I see this way (mine and the other way) are not convenient, I recommend you to only get the ID then fetch results from database and display values in your Edit Form, this will save you lots of time to fix URL and to prevent any conflict may happen.

Comment: Hi, I am looking on that direction, sending only the ID. 
I retreive next column (name) like this: 
<%
try{
  String id=request.getParameter("id");
    Connection con...;
 Statement st ...;
 resultset =statement.executeQuery("select name from table where id = " + id) ;
    while (resultset.next()) {
      String name;
      name = resultset.getString("name");
%>.  

If my table is:      
<tr>
  <td><label for="name">Name:  </label></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="name" id="name"></td>
</tr>.  

How can I insert the value "name" into the form as a default value ?